# How to access a particular key->value pair and exclude a specific key->value pair from an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, associative-array

I've an associative array named `$_SESSION[BASE_SESSION_NAME]['my_cart']`. For your reference I'm printing the array as below:

```
Array
(
    [6f993b72511c37f4ab4d7273066b8160] => Array
        (
            [pack_id] => 6f993b72511c37f4ab4d7273066b8160
            [pack_type] => test
            [pack_type_id] => 4
            [pack_name] => NEET XII Biology
            [pack_price] => 459.00
            [pack_validity] => Array
                (
                    [years] => 1
                    [months] => 0
                    [days] => 0
                )

        )

    [cart_summary] => Array
        (
            [total_no_packages] => 3
            [total_pack_price] => 1557
            [final_total_pack_price] => 1557
            [total_pack_discount] => 0
            [apply_deal_code] => 0
            [no_of_discounted_packages] => 0
        )

    [67f76ffae26ffdcde7a392c5534c972a] => Array
        (
            [pack_id] => 67f76ffae26ffdcde7a392c5534c972a
            [pack_type] => test
            [pack_type_id] => 4
            [pack_name] => NEET XII Chemistry
            [pack_price] => 599.00
            [pack_validity] => Array
                (
                    [years] => 1
                    [months] => 0
                    [days] => 0
                )

        )

    [31dc7c5d9b9cb5a2ba968e74efd4a475] => Array
        (
            [pack_id] => 31dc7c5d9b9cb5a2ba968e74efd4a475
            [pack_type] => test
            [pack_type_id] => 4
            [pack_name] => NEET XII Physics
            [pack_price] => 499.00
            [pack_validity] => Array
                (
                    [years] => 1
                    [months] => 0
                    [days] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to access only the key having pack_id value or a value ok key `pack_id`.
i.e.for example the value [31dc7c5d9b9cb5a2ba968e74efd4a475] or the value from key `pack_id`
as `[pack_id] => 31dc7c5d9b9cb5a2ba968e74efd4a475`.
But the issue is there is one more array present having key `[cart_summary]` and I don't want to use any thing from that array.
I've to fire a query on every such pack_id. So I want to fire a query withe the help of loop. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance. The query which I want to use is as follows:

```
SELECT package_type.package_type_name
FROM package_type
JOIN test_packages ON package_type.package_type_id = test_packages.test_pack_type_id
WHERE test_packages.test_pack_id = '$propsed_pack_id'
```

Comment: while looping(using foreach) through the array u can use a if condition to check whether the key is "cart_summary" or not.If its not then fire the query.Hope this will help

Comment: @saranbanerjee: I'm relatively new to this foreach over associative array concept. Can you provide me the code for it. I'll be really thankful to you.

Comment: ok I will provide it to you as an answer.

Comment: @saranbanerjee: ok,no problem. Thanks for helping me. Waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the foreach for the associative array you asked for in the comment

```
$mycart = $_SESSION[BASE_SESSION_NAME]['my_cart'];// where $mycart is the array structure
                                                  //as shown above in the question
foreach($mycart as $key=>$value)
{
     //where $key holds the pack_id i.e. the array key value
     $propsed_pack_id = $value['pack_id'];
     if($key != "cart_summary")
     {
         //execute you sql query
         $query = "SELECT package_type.package_type_name
         FROM package_type
         JOIN test_packages ON package_type.package_type_id =    
         test_packages.test_pack_type_id
         WHERE test_packages.test_pack_id = '$propsed_pack_id'";
         ......

     }
 }
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Comment: Thank you so much saran. It is really what I wanted. You saved my valuable time and efforts too. Thanks one again. I've marked your answer as accepted and upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`unset($arr["item"])` removes the item which has the key of "item" from the array called $arr.

Answer (score 1):

One way is you can directly put check for 'cart-summary' as told by saran banerjee.

But I would suggest, Instead of putting hard-coded check for 'cart-summary,' you can check for 'pack_id' key in the array. If it's there, execute query for that pack_id, otherwise not.

```
$mycart = $_SESSION[BASE_SESSION_NAME]['my_cart']; 

foreach($mycart as $key=>$value)
{
     //where $key holds the pack_id 
     $propsed_pack_id = isset($value['pack_id']) ? $value['pack_id'] : '';
     if($propsed_pack_id != "")
     {
         //execute you sql query
         $query = "SELECT package_type.package_type_name
         FROM package_type
         JOIN test_packages ON package_type.package_type_id =    
         test_packages.test_pack_type_id
         WHERE test_packages.test_pack_id = '$propsed_pack_id'";

     }
 }
```

Comment: :Thank you so much Nishu. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well what you want, you should use a loop and look for the correct key.

If your backend language is PHP.

```
foreach($_SESSION[BASE_SESSION_NAME]['my_cart'] as $cart) {
    if (isset($cart['pack_id'])) {
        // Here you get the pack id, only if exist as a key inside the array
    }
}
```

Hope this help...